# Simulating photo-realistic scenes (e.g. import Matterport3D dataset)

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to import 3D real scene to gazebo and later do simulations in that world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24885/simulating-photo-realistic-scenes-(e.g.-import-matterport3d-dataset)/) by [earny](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25798/earny/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It [looks like](https://support.matterport.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014357087-Matterport-Assets-You-Can-Download) Matterport supports exporting to OBJ, so you could load that into either Gazebo or Ignition.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1